# Is it possible to get private assembly key?

Tags: .net, assemblies

Is it possible to get private assembly key in .NET using only public token?

Thanks,
Alexey Z.

Comment: Why do you need the private key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, because otherwise signing assemblies would be pointless.

The developer of the Assembly keeps their private key secret so that any user of a signed Assembly can be sure it comes from who it claims to be from, preventing spoofing attacks.

If it becomes practical to calculate private keys from public keys [a lot of security measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Examples) - not just the signing of .NET Assemblies - will become worthless overnight.